# MYSQL insert error when trying to insert single columns

Tags: mysql, database, insert

Trying to do an insert in MySQL and getting an error that I cannot figure out.  The syntax (at least from my perspective) is right.  I've tried tinkering around with a lot of little things and cannot figure it out.  Also tried dropping and recreating the table and it still happens.

Insert Code:

```
 insert into `apType` (`type`) values (`private`),(`public`),(`military`);
```

table creation code:

```
 CREATE TABLE `apType`(
`id` int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` varchar(255) NOT NULL
 )ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

error code generated:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'private' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a correct SQL - notice single quotes on values being inserted:

```
INSERT INTO `apType` (`type`) VALUES ('private'),('public'),('military');
```

What your SQL is actually doing is trying to insert values from fields private, public and military - which in fact do not exist.